# Check extra parameters with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Please give a hint in Spring Security, how can I check additional parameters during user login.
For example, to check not only  "username" and "password", but also if he confirmed his registration with email link;
All data is stored in DB and i can get it easily with my implementation of UserDetailsService;

But how to make the security service to pay attention to the additional parameter "isValidated"?
I'm using Spring 3.2.0 now;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to create a custom [`AuthenticationProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) or to extend an existing one. In your case it might be sufficient to extend for instance the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and put the logic for checking whether the account is confirmed in `additionalAuthenticationChecks()` method.

Here is an example:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // Perform the checks from the super class
        super.additionalAuthenticationChecks(userDetails, authentication);

        // Cast the UserDetails to the implementation you use
        User user = (User) userDetails;

        // Check the confirmed status
        if (!user.isAccountConfirmed()) {
            throw new AccountNotConfirmedException("Account is not confirmed yet.");
        }
    }

    public static class AccountNotConfirmedException extends AuthenticationException {
        public AccountNotConfirmedException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

}
```

Your implementation of `UserDetails` should contain the information about account confirmation status. You can map this information in your implementation of `UserDetailsService`.

## Option 2

Edit: Now that I look at it, the first solution is a bit overcomplicated. You can easily solve this problem without using custom `AuthenticationProvider`. Just make sure that `isEnabled()` of your `UserDetails` implementation returns `false` if the account is not confirmed. If the `enabled` property is `false` authentication will not be allowed (this is automatically taken care of by Spring Security).

The first solution might still be useful if you want explicitly handle the `AccountNotConfirmedException` in `AuthenticationFailureHandler` for instance.

Comment: i used that second option before your first answer. It works, but it less have less possibilities to  costumizeble. So i still prefer way with overwriting AccountNotConfirmedException

Comment: Option 2 was perfect! Thanks.