# Spring security. add restriction for user log in

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I have following spring security config:

```
<http auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager">
        <form-login login-page="/" 
            default-target-url="/member/personalAccount"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler" />

        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/common/*" filters="none" /> -->
        <intercept-url ..../>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
        <port-mappings>
         <port-mapping http="${http.port}" https="${https.port}"/>
        </port-mappings>
    </http>

    ....


    <authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager">
        <!-- <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService"> -->
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                users-by-username-query="select email,password,prop_was_moderated from terminal_user where email = ?"  
                authorities-by-username-query="select email,user_role from terminal_user where email = ?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Now I want to add new column to `terminal_user` table.
This column called `prop_confirmed`

I want to achieve that only user who has `prop_confirmed` as `true` can be log in.

Can you help me to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it is to hardcode the `prop_confirmed` condition in `users-by-username-query`. That way if user is not confirmed, it will be as if they don't exist and the authentication will fail:

```
select email,password,prop_was_moderated from terminal_user
    where email = ? AND prop_confirmed = TRUE
```

There are other (and possibly cleaner) solutions, such as customizing `AuthenticationManager`. Take a look at my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658312/1291150) regarding similar question for more detailed description of these options.

Comment: can you explain when instead of *?* will replace with concrete value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to know which Spring Security component takes care of executing the query and setting the `?` placeholders?

Comment: Yes.I want to know it.

Comment: @gstackoverflow That happens in `UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(username)` method. The `UserDetailsService` instance which will be used is created automatically by Spring (based on `<jdbc-user-service>` element in your configuration.)

Comment: one more question) where spring takes value to replcace **?** ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Well that is the username parameter in `loadUserByUsername` method. And the username is retrieved from `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` in `AuthenticationProvider` which then calls the `loadByUsername` method with the retrieved username.