# Spring Security: Check If Extra Fields in the Database are false and Inform User Why He Cannot Login if he is Not Enabled

Tags: spring

I am trying to implement Spring Security for my website. I have done this so far and it works like charm. This code below is working but I have others fields in the database that I want to verify before authenticating the user. What I want is to check the if the fields " deletedByRecommender " and " deletedByAdministrator " are false before authenticating the user. Not only I want to check if the user is completely enabled but I want to print a message to the user with the reason why he cannot login if he is not enabled. I was looking into filters but wasnt able to make it work. How do I make this?

```html
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head> 
 
<title>Recommendation Book</title>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

</script>

</h:head>
 
<h:body>

<div class="Geral">

<h:form name="f" method="post">

 <table>
  <tr><td>E-mail:</td><td><input type="email" name="username" value="" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" value="" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Remember Me:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" /></td></tr>
  <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
  <tr><td colspan="2" style="color:red">Invalid email and password.</td></tr>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
  <tr><td colspan="2" style="color:red">You have been logged out.</td></tr>
  </c:if>
 </table>

</h:form>

</div>

</h:body>
 
</html>
```

```html
package recBook;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

 public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
  super(WebSecurityConfig.class);
 }
}
```

```html
package recBook;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
 private DataSource dataSource;

 @Autowired
 public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth
   .jdbcAuthentication()
    .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
 }
 
 @Bean
 public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 }
 
 @Bean(name = "dataSource")
 public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
     DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
     driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/RecBookSpringDB");
     driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
     driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("**************");
     return driverManagerDataSource;
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
   .authorizeRequests()                                                                
    .antMatchers("/index.jsf", "/userPage.jsf").permitAll()  
    .antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("Administrator") 
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
   .formLogin().failureUrl("/login.jsf?error")
    .loginPage("/login.jsf")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
   .logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .permitAll()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.jsf?logout=true")
    .and()
   .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
    .and()
   .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied.xhtml")
    .and()
   .csrf();
 }

}
```

```html
CREATE  TABLE users (
 id SERIAL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
 enabled TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 deletedByRecommender BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 deletedByAdministrator BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 deleteReason CHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT 'Approved',
 lastUpdatedOn TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 createdOn TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (username)
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check extra parameters with Spring Security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658030/check-extra-parameters-with-spring-security). There are a lot of threads about  this on so. This one has a pretty comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I was trying to do by using good old sessions and by implementing an UserDetailsService interface. The whole code is down below. Any question just shot me a question. If you see anything wrong just tell me.

```html
/*
 *
 * This is how I hash the password when inserting the user on database 
 *
 */

BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode("test");
   
Users users = new Users();
Authorities authorities = new Authorities();
   
users.setUsername("Username");
users.setPassword(hashedPassword);
   
authorities.setUsername("Username");
authorities.setAuthority("Authority");
   
new RegisterDAO().insert(users, authorities);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head> 
 
<title>Recommendation Book</title>

<style>

label.error {
 float: right;
 color: red;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 1em;
 padding: 0.75em;
 border-radius: 7px;
 -moz-border-radius: 7px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 7px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
 border: 2px solid red;
 background-color: white;
}

span.error {
 color: red;
 font-weight: bold;
}

span.message {
 color: green;
 font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

</h:head>
 
<h:body>

<div class="Geral">

<h:form method="post" class="Login">

 <table>
  <tr><td>E-mail:</td><td><input type="email" id="username" name="username" value="" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" value="test" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Remember Me:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" /></td></tr>

  <c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}">
  <c:choose>
   <c:when test="#{SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message == 'Bad credentials'}">
    <tr><td colspan="2"><span class="error">Wrong Email and Password</span></td></tr>
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise test="#{SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message == 'User is disabled'}">
    <tr><td colspan="2"><span class="error">Recommender is Disabled</span></td></tr>
   </c:otherwise>
   <c:otherwise>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><span class="error"><h:outputText value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/></span></td></tr>
   </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
   <c:if test="#{sessionScope['SpringError'] != null}">
    <tr><td colspan="2"><span class="error"><h:outputText escape="false" value="#{sessionScope['SpringError']}"/></span></td></tr>
   </c:if>
  </c:if>

  <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
   <tr><td colspan="2" ><span class="message">You have been logged out.</span></td></tr>
  </c:if>
 </table>

</h:form>

</div>

</h:body>
 
</html>
```

```html
package recBook;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

@Resource
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

 @Autowired
 private HttpServletRequest request;
 
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
  Users users = null;
  Authorities authority = null;
  try {
   users = new UsersDAO().select(username);
   authority = new AuthoritiesDAO().select(username);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  Boolean enabled = true;
  String usernameOutro = "anonymousUser";
  String passwordOutro = "WrongPassword";
  Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("WrongAuthority");
  
  request.getSession().setAttribute("SpringError", "");
  
  if(users != null && authority != null) {
   
   usernameOutro = users.getUsername();
   passwordOutro = users.getPassword();
   authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(authority.getAuthority());
   
   /*
    * 
    * Sets the login invalid for test
    * 
    */
   //users.setEnabled(0);
   //users.setDeletedByAdministrator(true);
   //users.setDeletedByRecommender(true);
   
   String errors = "";
   
   if(users.getEnabled().equals(0)) {
    errors = "You Are Not Enabled to Login";
    enabled = false;
   } 
   
   if(users.getDeletedByAdministrator().equals(true)) {
    if(!errors.equals("")) { errors = errors + "<br />"; }
    errors = errors + "This RB Account Was Deleted By Recommendation Book Administrators";
    enabled = false;
   } 
   
   if(users.getDeletedByRecommender().equals(true)) {
    if(!errors.equals("")) { errors = errors + "<br />"; }
    errors = errors + "This RB Account Was Deleted By The Owner of This RB Account";
    enabled = false;
   }
   
   request.getSession().setAttribute("SpringError", errors);
  }
  
  // User(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, 
  // boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
  return new User(usernameOutro, passwordOutro, enabled, true, true, true, authorities);
 }

}
```

```html
package recBook;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
 @Autowired
 MyUserDetails myUserDetails;
 
 @Autowired
 @Bean(name = "myUserDetails")
 public MyUserDetails MyUserDetails() {
  MyUserDetails myUserDetails = new MyUserDetails();
  return myUserDetails;
 }
 
 @Autowired
 public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.userDetailsService(MyUserDetails()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
 }
 
 @Bean
 public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
   .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/index.jsf", "/userPage.jsf").permitAll()  
    .antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("Administrator") 
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and()
   .formLogin().failureUrl("/login.jsf?error=true")
    .loginPage("/login.jsf")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
   .logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .permitAll()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.jsf?logout=true")
    .and()
   .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
    .and()
   .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied.xhtml")
    .and()
   .csrf();
 }

}
```

```html
<!-- Put this in web.xml -->
<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```